# column comparison of two dataframe, return df with mismatches python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison, mismatch

I want to print two dataframes that print the rows where there is a mismatch in a given column, here the "second_column":
`"first_column" is a key value that identify same product in both dataframes`

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    data1 = {
        'first_column': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'],
        'second_column': ['1', '2', '2'],
        'third_column': ['1', '2', '2'],
        'fourth_column': ['1', '2', '2']
    }
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
    
    print(df1)
    
    test = df1['second_column'].nunique()
    
    data2 = {
        'first_column': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'],
        'second_column': ['3', '4', '2'],
        'third_column': ['1', '2', '2'],
        'fourth_column': ['1', '2', '2']
    }
    
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
    print(df2)
```

[image]

expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC
btw, you screenshots don't match your DF definition

```
df1.loc[~df1['second_column'].isin(df2['second_column'])]
```

```
first_column    second_column   third_column    fourth_column
0   1   1   1   1
```

```
df2.loc[~df2['second_column'].isin(df1['second_column'])]
```

```
first_column    second_column   third_column    fourth_column
0   1   3   1   1
1   2   4   2   2
```

Comment: @yoopiyo, does this solution worked and answer your question?

Comment: If I had to compare on both second and third column how would you write it?

Comment: like this   df1.loc[~(df1['second_column'].isin(df2['second_column']) &
          df1['second_column'].isin(df2['third_column'])
         )]

Answer (score 1):

the `compare` method can do what you want.

```
different_rows = df1.compare(df2, align_axis=1).index
df1.loc[different_rows]
```

With this method, one important point is if there are extra rows (index) then it will not return a difference.

or if you want to find differences in one column only, you can first `join` on the index then check if the join matches

```
joined_df = df1.join(df2['second_column'], rsuffix='_df2')
diff = joined_df['second_column']!=joined_df['second_column_df2']
print(joined_df.loc[diff, df1.columns])
```

Comment: Thanks, I would like to compare the rows only based on the value of the "second column", let's say that "first_column" are key values both in the first and in the second dataframe I want to compare